# linear approximation of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have the function $(5x-3)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}x)+\ln(2x-1)$. I am asked to compute the linearization of f at $a=1$ which I did. The answer is:

$L(x)=3+\frac{29}{12}(x-1)$

However, I am then asked to use this approximation to estimate the value of $(7.5)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\sin(\frac{9\pi}{20})+\ln(\frac{4}{5})$

What value do I plug in for $L(x)$ exactly? I'm a little confused about that...

Is it just 0.5? Since the cube root evaluate at 1 gives 7 and 7.5 is 0.5 above that.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the partial linearization you got for each term, because $x$ is not the same for all terms (so you can't use $L(x)$ directly).

The second part of the question actually doesn't want you to use $a=1$ at all. You're meant to use the closest known value so you get a reasonable approximation.

The first term: write $7.5=8-0.5$ and develop around $8$, for which you know $\sqrt[3]{8}=2$. For the second term, use $\frac{9\pi}{20}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{20}$. Again, the origin is chosen so the value is obvious. For the last term, $\frac45=1-\frac{1}{5}$ is ok (using $\ln (1+x)\approx x$ at $x=-\frac{1}{5}$).

Comment: Ahh okay. Haha, I never did linerization like this before so this tripped me. I would just all the values after right?

Comment: I believe they meant for you to choose your origins ($a$) wisely! For the first term, $a=8$ is good because $\sqrt[3]{8}=2$ is known. For the second one, you may want to take $a=\pi/2$ which is close and known... and for the last one, $a=1$ is good. This way, you can compute all this by hand without a calculator.

Comment: Would I just add the values after then?

Comment: Ohh never mind I got it myself. If I actually solve fox x in the value given in the question, they all happen to equal x=0.90. So 5x +3= 7.5,  pi/2x=9pi/20 and 2x-1=4/5. Solvng for x gives 0.90 so I would plug that in.